# How to insert links to file in LyX?

Tags: hyperref, lyx, links

I am writing a report in LyX. I want to insert a link to a PDF file. I used the hyperlink feature available in LyX. Then in the target field I gave the path. In the name field I gave a random name. Then I selected "file" button. But then I am getting an error message saying unknown parameter field. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: When/where does this error appear?